# popup outside of a function call

Tags: java, android

please can someone assist-

I have a popup that I have created in a function called pop that creates a popupwindow. I also have another function that when a user clicks on a button in the popupwindow, it dismisses the popupWindow. I have created a separate function for the dismissal. I would like to pass the popupwindow into the dismiss function - what is the best way to do this. I would like to reuse the dismiss function.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void popup(View v) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alert_dialog,null);
    final PopupWindow popup= new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    View vi=(View) findViewByID(R.id.Layout);
    popup.showAtLocation(vi, 0, 20, -50);

}

public void dismiss(View v) {
     popup.dismiss();

} 
}
```

My dismiss method is executed from within a resource layout file:

```
<Button
    android:text="cancel"
    android:onClick="dismiss"/>
```

Comment: Just do `public void dismiss(PopupWindow popup)`.
Make sure popup is initalized before dismiss is called.

Comment: How you are calling `dismiss()`?? from where ?? Show us the  code..!!

Comment: hi calling dimissed from a layout resource. Will update above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code as below: Popup will be created everytime when you call `popup()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PopupWindow mPopup = null;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void popup(View v) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alert_dialog,null);

        // Use global variable instead of local.
        //final PopupWindow popup= new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mPopup= new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        View vi=(View) findViewByID(R.id.Layout);
        mPopup.showAtLocation(vi, 0, 20, -50);
    }

    public void dismiss(View v) {
        if (mPopup != null && mPopup.isShowing()) {
            mPopup.dismiss();
        }    
    } 
}
```

And, I have a question about position value of `mPopup.showAtLocation(vi, 0, 20, -50);`. Is it right position of `y = -50`?

I think this popup will be displayed out of moniter.

Comment: If I were a billionaire I would give you a million dollars now - thanks your solution worked. It is out of the screen slightly, I am just trying to get the functionality right at this stage not worried about the look of the app.

Comment: That's my pleasure. :) Also, I have an opinion about your functions. If this functions are not override, I recommend you to delete parameter `View v` that is unused in each functions.

Comment: thanks for that: thats 1 thing i was not understanding - what does @override actually mean

Comment: If you make an object - extended class that have abstract function, or an interface - , you may implement functions of that object. They are called `override functions`. And, `@override` is an annotation which means "This function is override." in Java/Android.

Answer (score 0):

create global variable for PopupWindow.

```
    private PopupWindow popup;

    public void popup(View v) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alert_dialog,null);
         popup= new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        View vi=(View) findViewByID(R.id.Layout);
        popup.showAtLocation(vi, 0, 20, -50);

    }

public void dismiss(View v) {
     popup.dismiss();

}
```

Comment: does not work - receive the following error: IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of activity. I have included additional code above.

Comment: where you adding globla variable it is in main class right

Comment: correct it is in the main class above the onCreate function.